# Cannot import PyBrain after installation on OSX 10.6.8

Tags: python, pybrain

Check the python version

```
✈  python --version
Python 2.7.2
```

List the packages within the `virtualenv`

```
✈  pip freeze
PyBrain==0.3
numpy==1.6.1
scipy==0.10.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Load the intepreter

```
>>> import numpy
>>> print numpy.__version__
1.6.1
>>> import scipy
>>> print scipy.__version__
0.10.1
>>> import pybrain
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/Users/milktrader/.virtualenvs/pybrain/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pybrain/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from structure.__init__ import *
  File "/Users/milktrader/.virtualenvs/pybrain/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pybrain/structure/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from modules.__init__ import *
  File "/Users/milktrader/.virtualenvs/pybrain/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pybrain/structure/modules/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from gate import GateLayer, DoubleGateLayer, MultiplicationLayer, SwitchLayer
  File "/Users/milktrader/.virtualenvs/pybrain/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pybrain/structure/modules/gate.py", line 11, in <module>
from pybrain.tools.functions import sigmoid, sigmoidPrime
  File "/Users/milktrader/.virtualenvs/pybrain/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pybrain/tools/functions.py", line 4, in <module>
from scipy.linalg import inv, det, svd
  File "/Users/milktrader/.virtualenvs/pybrain/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/__init__.py", line 116, in <module>
from basic import *
  File "/Users/milktrader/.virtualenvs/pybrain/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/basic.py", line 14, in <module>
from scipy.linalg import calc_lwork
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/milktrader/.virtualenvs/pybrain/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/calc_lwork.so, 2): Symbol not found: __gfortran_concat_string
  Referenced from: /Users/milktrader/.virtualenvs/pybrain/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/calc_lwork.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/milktrader/.virtualenvs/pybrain/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/calc_lwork.so, 2): Symbol not found: __gfortran_concat_string
```

I'm not sure - as I haven't messed with this library before - but do you need to compile one of those packages with Fortran support? When I installed numpy/scipy on my Mac up at work, I had to install [GFortran](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran) so all the bindings and underpinnings of the frameworks would be set correctly. Perhaps that's why scipy is dying on you.

Comment: I had previously installed the GNU fortran compiler http://r.research.att.com/tools/ and also invoked `brew gfortran` for good measure. I fear it's the gcc compiler that is 'kinda' working. I googled the calc_lwork.so file to no avail. Also, I both global installed `scipy` and virtualenv installed `scipy` and got the same error from `pybrain` and no warnings from `scipy`

Comment: `scipy` was using the ATT Fortran compiler not the one supplied by `brew`. I uninstalled the ATT Fortran compiler. Uninstalled `scipy` and `pybrain` too. Then installed `scipy` again. This time it used the  gfortran compiler and `pybrain` was able to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because scipy is not installed by default on the OSX python.

Try this to prove

```
>>> import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named scipy
>>>
```

Comment: I updated the post to demonstrate that scipy and numpy both load properly. Thanks.